# How to write a JSON to file in Java

Tags: json, gson

I am new to writing JSON to file using Java. I have request to be sent in the following format and needs to be written in Java.

```
{
Name : "sam",
"Id":"1234",
"Values": {
            "Car":"Maruti"
           },
"Price":"100000"
}
```

Please help.

Comment: How are you receiving the JSON array? As string or object?

Comment: do you know how to write a string to a file using java?

Comment: Here's a short video that'll show you [how to write JSON data to a file.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qEpxIARKxE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import **json.org** and try this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); //creates main json
json.put("Name", "sam");
json.put("Id", 1234);

JSONObject valuesJson = new JSONObject(); //another object
valuesJson.put("Car", "Maruti");

json.put("Values", valuesJson); //puts a json inside another

String jsonString = json.toString();

//next, saves the file:
PrintWriter out1 = null;
try {
    out1 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\YOURNAME\\Documents\\json.txt"));
    out1.write(jsonString);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("error: " + ex.toString());
}
```

Don't forget to set the file path correctly!

Comment: It working but the new lines in the JSON are not there.Also the order of the key value pair in the JSON is altered. {"Values":{"Car":"Maruti"},"Id":1234,"Name":"sam"}  I want to say that I need a .json file with new lines after each key value pair. Please help.

Comment: the order of the lines inside a json should not matter, so for the new lines. Any parser will recognize it. Well, it is possible to fix the lines with json.toString(4) instead of json.toString().