# Is it possible to extract the JSON of Firebase Database from Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I have an application in Android Studio that functions perfectly well, I want to ask if I can extract its Firebase Realtime Database JSON tree structure so I can implement it on my own Firebase console as well, and change the data accordingly.

Comment: You can infer the json structure from pojo classes for that data or the maps when the data is saved to firebase, or look at the connected firebase project in the console to see how data is structured, but as for extracting the JSON tree structure from Android Studio I doubtful that possible or if possible easy to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to get the entire database through Java code?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes I was thinking of trying to get the JSON File structure from Java Code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to extract the JSON of the Firebase Realtime Database?

Technically, it's possible.

According to your last comment:

> Yes I was thinking of trying to get the JSON File structure from Java Code.

If you need to get the structure in Java code, you have to go through your entire database and map each node into the corresponding JSON structure and in the end, [save it to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499865/how-to-write-a-json-to-file-in-java).

However, if you need it fast, you can directly download it from the console. To achieve that, simply open your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), choose your project, select your database, click download the JSON file from the right side, using the "Export JSON" option.